# Low level Android Bluetooth keyboard access...?

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard, hid

Long story short: I recently wrote a plugin for PhoneGap on Android to connect to Bluetooth **serial devices** and pass that data through to Javascript.  I have a bluetooth scale, and a bluetooth USB scanner going, and they work great.  (Though I did lose some hair learning how to do it.)

The USB scanner I have has to be returned to a client, and we bought our own scanner.  This one, however, uses a HID keyboard device.

Any suggestions on how to proceed in implementing support for these?  Do I need to write my own soft 'keyboard' to deal with this, or is there a lower-level way to do it?